# How to register a UDF in AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, user-defined-functions, amazon-athena

I have created a UDF using AWS Lambda and I can run query using below syntax:

```sql
USING EXTERNAL FUNCTION ai_func(review VARCHAR) RETURNS VARCHAR LAMBDA 'xxx-ai-xxx-genai-udf'
SELECT review, ai_func(review) as ai_review from gen_ai.xxxxxxx_table;
```

But, is there a way to register the function like this?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ai_func(review varchar) RETURNS VARCHAR 
LAMBDA 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:function:xxx-ai-xxx-genai-udf';
```

This errors out:

> line 1:19: mismatched input 'FUNCTION'. Expecting: 'MATERIALIZED', 'MULTI', 'PROTECTED', 'VIEW'

I want to register it so that multiple users can use it and users don't like to use `USING EXTERNAL FUNCTION` syntax. `CREATE FUNCTION` is supported by Redshift, Hive and few other databases.

Comment: No, that is not supported by Athena. Are you querying data from Redshift, or direct from S3? If you are using Athena to query from Redshift, then you might be able to create the function in Redshift and simply reference in the SQL, and Athena would pass that SQL query to Redshift.

Comment: I'm using Athena to query data from S3.

Comment: The [Querying with user defined functions - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-udf.html) documentation only shows the first method as being available.

Comment: You are right.  Is there a way to register it from backend?